# Scrapy (Python) - skipping section of site

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm working on web-crawler collecting data from store's site https://www.promocje.zabka.pl.
Sometimes it happens that a product doesn't have price attached in normal way (i.e. in span "product-price-integer"). It causes troubles in the loop due to different sizes of arrays. I could limit iterations to the length of the shortest array, but it is likely to distort the results (shifts).
Here's my question: **how can I just skip whole div of the product where one of fields (price-integer, price-decimal) is empty or doesn't exist?**

Here's my code (note that amount usually is not needed since I can extract more accurate value from product's name; that's the reason for if)

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name        = "zabka"
    allowed_domains = ["zabka.pl"]
    start_urls  = ["http://promocje.zabka.pl"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs     = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles  = hxs.select('//div[@class="product-description"]/h2/text()').extract()
        prices  = hxs.select('//span[@class="product-price-integer"]/text()').extract()
        prices1 = hxs.select('//span[@class="product-price-decimal"]/text()').extract()
        amounts = hxs.select('//p[@class="product-unit"]/text()').extract()

        list = []

        for i in range(len(titles)):
            split = titles[i].split(",")
            if len(split) > 1:
                list1 = split[0] + "  -  " + prices[i] + "," + prices1[i] + "  -  " + split[len(split) - 1]
            else:
                list1 = titles[i] + "  -  " + prices[i] + "," + prices1[i] + "  -  " + amounts[i]
            list.append(list1)

        for l in list:
            item = NettutsItem()
            item["title"] = l
            yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried

```
scrapy shell http://promocje.zabka.pl/
```

And the main idea is you should use `div` as starting point for your next selectors.

```
In [32]: div  = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-description"]')[0]
In [33]: div.css('h2::text').extract()
Out[33]: [u'Babka marmur Dan Cake, 40 g']

In [34]: div.css('span[class="product-price-integer"]::text').extract()
Out[34]: [u'1']
```

Try this approach

```
def parse(self, response):
list = []
for div in response.xpath('//div[@class="product-description"]'):
    price = div.css('span[class="product-price-integer"]::text').extract()
    price1 = div.css('span[class="product-price-decimal"]::text').extract()
    title = div.css('h2::text').extract()[0].split(",")
    amount = div.css('p[class="product-unit"]::text').extract()[0]

    if price and price1:
        price = price[0]
        price1 = price1[0]
        item = NettutsItem()
        # do some stuff with item
        yield item
```

Code may be more pretty.

Comment: Thanks for response. I've tested this and I'm afraid it doesn't work. This if-else statement seems to be executed after creating whole lists above, so it can't be used to filter them dynamically. To be more specific on what I need: I don't want to create item for product which doesn't have price (product-price-integer), I want to skip it entirely.

Comment: I corrected the answer, check it up once more. I replaced xpath to css selectors. Now they're search elements currently in div rather than by all html page and return one element instead of full array. You can check your selectors in `scrapy shell` console.